# Infinite sum of GEM distribution converges to 1

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory

The Griffiths-Engen-McCloskey (GEM) distribution is common in Bayesian nonparemetrics. In particular, suppose we have a sequence $(\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots)$ where each $\pi_i \in (0,1)$. One constructs a discrete distribution $(w_i)$ using the following rule:

$$
w_i := \pi_i\prod_{l=1}^{i-1}(1-\pi_l).
$$

The claim is that $(w_1,w_2,\dots)$ is a distribution, and so

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}w_i = 1.
$$

By imagining the process as successively breaking a stick of unit-length, the results is intuitively true, but how can one formally show that the infinite sum equals 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $q_i = 1-\pi_i$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots$, and define $$s_i = \sum_{j=1}^i w_j.$$  Also define $p_i = \prod_{j=1}^i q_j$, so that $w_i = \pi_i p_{i-1}.$  Then I claim $$s_i = 1 - p_i.$$  To see this, we proceed by induction.  For $i = 1$, the result is trivially true:  $$s_1 = w_1 = \pi_1 = 1 - q_1 = 1 - p_1.$$ Then $$s_i = s_{i-1} + w_i = (1-p_{i-1}) + \pi_i p_{i-1} = 1 - (1-\pi_i)p_{i-1} = 1 - q_i p_{i-1} = 1 - p_i,$$ and this proves the induction step.

Consequently, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - p_n = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - \pi_i),$$ and this last expression obviously converges almost surely to $1$ for $\pi_i \in (0,1)$.

Comment: The penultimate term should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}1-p_n$? Thanks!

Comment: @jesterII Indeed; it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample:

Let $\pi_n = \dfrac{1}{2^n+2}$

then $\displaystyle \prod_{l=1}^{i-1}(1-\pi_l) = \dfrac12 + \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ (as can be shown by induction)

and thus $w_i = \dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}$

with $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i = \dfrac12 \not = 1$

Comment: Right, I should have noted that $\pi_i$ are drawn from a $Beta(1,\alpha)$ distribution. I believe the set of all $(\pi_i)$ that satisfy your example have measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what heropup wrote, but in a way I find more transparent. We rewrite the $w_{i}$ in terms of $q_{i} = 1 - \pi_{i}$. Then
\begin{align*}
    w_{i} 
    &= (1 - q_{i}) \prod_{j < i} q_{j} \\
    &= \left( \prod_{j < i} q_{j} \right) - \left(  \prod_{j < i+1} q_{j} 
    \right)
 \end{align*}
Summing up the $w_{i}$ gives a telescoping series,
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i = 1}^{k} w_{i}
    &= \left( \prod_{j < 1} q_{j} \right) - \left(  \prod_{j < k+1} q_{j}
    \right) \\
    &= 1 - \left( \prod_{j < k+1} q_{j} \right)
 \end{align*}
Taking the limit as $k \to \infty$, the product will go to zero as long as the $q_{i}$ don't tend to $1$, or at least not too quickly. Assuming that the $\pi_{i}$ (and thus the $q_{i}$) are i.i.d. random on $(0, 1)$ is sufficient to get convergence to zero almost surely. Alternatively, if we want a stronger conclusion there are other conditions we could put on them (for example, see the 2-parameter GEM).